Android CountDownTimer calls in order. Wait for one to finish and start the other
I’m trying to create a sequence of CountDownTimers in my Android app using Java, where each timer starts only after the previous one completes. The sequence needs to repeat for a set number of rounds, with a few variations (like skipping the rest period on the last round). Here’s the order I want:

Start a 3-second countdown timer. WAIT TO FINISH
After that, start the main timer. WAIT TO FINISH
Then, start the rest timer.
Repeat the sequence for a specified number of rounds.

I’m having trouble ensuring that each timer runs sequentially, even when trying to use a while loop. Any suggestions on how to handle this? This is what I have so far (trying to use While Loop):


package com.example.empty_tv_test;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView textView;
    private Boolean isThreeSecondsCountDownOver = true;
    private Boolean isTimerRunning = true;
    private Boolean isMainCounterOver = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        // Initialize the TextView
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewTimer);

        // Start CDT 1
        //Start the CountDown
        //Avoiding infite runs
        boolean didThreeSecondsRun = false;
        boolean didMainTimerRun = false;
        boolean didRestTimerRun = false;
        while (isTimerRunning) {
            //Run for as many rounds as necessary /
            //TO-DO Wrap this with FOR loops for Rounds
            //First Check: Is 3 Seconds Countdown?
            if (isThreeSecondsCountDownOver && !didThreeSecondsRun){
                StartCountDownTimer(2000, 1);
                //Turn 3 SEC off
                didThreeSecondsRun = true;
            }
            if (!isThreeSecondsCountDownOver && !didMainTimerRun){
                //3 Seconds Coundown is over, start main counter
                StartCountDownTimer(7000, 2);
                didMainTimerRun = true;
                isTimerRunning = false;
            }
            if(isMainCounterOver && !didRestTimerRun){
                //Finally the Rest Round is Fired
                StartCountDownTimer(8000, 3);
                didThreeSecondsRun = true;
                isTimerRunning = false;
            }
        }


    }//END of onCreate

//TimerType: 1. 3 SEC, 2. Main, 3. Rest
    public void StartCountDownTimer(int time, int whichTimerType){
        new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // Used for formatting digits to be in 2 digits only
                NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
                long hour = (millisUntilFinished / 3600000) % 24;
                long min = (millisUntilFinished / 60000) % 60;
                long sec = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                textView.setText(f.format(hour) + ":" + f.format(min) + ":" + f.format(sec));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // When the task is over it will print 00:00:00
                textView.setText("ZZZZZZZ");
                if (whichTimerType == 1){
                    isThreeSecondsCountDownOver = false;
                }
                if (whichTimerType == 2){
                    isMainCounterOver = true;
                }
                if (whichTimerType == 3){
                    isMainCounterOver = false;
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }
}




Sounds like you want each timer task to start the next one.

@JohnBollinger I'm trying to avoid using the onFinish() to have a timer calling the other because they will have different setups. It will become a mess.

It's not obvious to me why that should be.  But perhaps you don't realize that you can create named timer classes instead of using anonymous ones such as you demonstrate in the question? That would be cleaner than putting three anonymous timer classes in the same method even if one doesn't start the next.

@JohnBollinger would that fix is issue that I have on having the each timer being called after the previous one is done? If so, can you show it to me? TIA

If each timer starts the next as it finishes then yes, that should prevent any of them running concurrently.  That's a separate consideration from using named timer classes, which is mainly about tidiness and modularity.  I'm unsure what about that you want me to show you.

@JohnBollinger I see your two points. I'm trying to avoid using the onFinish() at the end of the countdown, which is the only way I can I think of to have one timer call in the other. My logic was more like: Start a timer, wait, start the next, wait, etc. I'm obviously not ask experienced as you and I appreciate your time and help

You said you wanted to avoid onFinish() because it would be difficult / messy. I still don't see why that would be, and onFinish() is exactly the place to put work that should be done when a timer expires.  Such as, in your case, start the next timer.  My comments about using named timer classes were a stab at addressing the messiness consideration. I can't really write an answer because your continuing aversion to using onFinish() leaves me uncertain about what the problem you're trying to solve really is.

Instead of using while loop, maybe you can trying recursion?

I can't excatly understand your question, so I think you are trying to do some action after current timer onFinsh, and combine some timer to a group, then you can decide how many rounds the group run.
I write a recursion version below:
int red, green, blue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    root = findViewById(R.id.root);
    button.setOnClickListener(v->{
            startCountDownTimer(1000, 1, 2);
        });
    red = getColor(R.color.red);
    green = getColor(R.color.green);
    blue = getColor(R.color.blue);
}

public void startCountDownTimer(int time, int timerType, int rounds){
    if (rounds == 0) return;
    new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            int restRounds = rounds;
            if (timerType == 1){
                root.setBackgroundColor(red);
                startCountDownTimer(2000, 2, restRounds);
            }
            if (timerType == 2){
                startCountDownTimer(3000, 3, restRounds);
                root.setBackgroundColor(blue);
            }
            if (timerType == 3){
                restRounds -= 1;
                startCountDownTimer(1000, 1, restRounds);
                root.setBackgroundColor(green);
            }

        }
    }.start();
}

I let the rootView change background when onFinish.
